# When trying to initialise my secondary Hard Drive (Samsung1TB), it's blocking me from completing both options (MBR and GPT)

Tags: boot, partitioning, drivers

Brand new PC, brand new Hard Drive. I've not yet stored anything on this, as I've only just realised that everything I'm installing is going onto my SSD 240gb, which I want to change.

When trying to initialise my secondary hard drive in disk management, it is seen as:
Disk 0
Unknown
Not Initiated

When I select GPT to initialise, it says 'The specified disk is not convertible because the size is less than the minimum size required for GPT disks'.

When I select MBR, it says 'Incorrect function'.

I'm new with this kind of technology, so I'd appreciate any help provided. I've checked out multiple other threads in relation to the same topic, but none have seemed to help my case.

I can provide further details if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

With a new computer, the secondary disk should have been usable immediately,
without initialization.

So it seems like your secondary hard drive is dead on arrival,
or that some connection was jarred loose during transport.

As the computer is new, it must still be under warranty, so use it rather than
trying to fix it yourself (which might void that warranty).

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for the problem you are facing is a faulty/dead on arrival disk, since you seem to be following the procedure for initializing a disk correctly. It should work on either MBR or GPT, and the error saying the size is less that the minimum size required on GPT makes me suspect that no data can be written at all in your disk (1TB is far bigger than that).

Here you can see a problem similar to yours: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/disk-cant-initialize-cant-convert-to-gpt-and-shows/b869a822-9660-4a5d-a92e-ca50d77c5cc1 , and seems to point at a faulty disk aswell.

So, as harrymc stated, you should contact the seller for warranty, they should tell you the next steps (if you bought the computer assembled, most likely you will have to send the whole thing, otherwise they will ask only for the disk)